# Dart 3 get doc in collection across a routing system

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to get the return of a `Future<>` function across my routing system.

I got an error:

> The non-nullable local variable 'page' must be assigned before it can be used

raised by the return of my class `RouteGenerator`.

My `RouteGenerator.dart` :

```
import 'package:chope_ton_diplome/services/CommonService.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route generate(RouteSettings s) {
    Widget page;
    CommonService commonService = CommonService();

    switch (s.name) {
      case RouteConsts.termsScreen:
        ArgumentsAuth args = s.arguments as ArgumentsAuth;
        commonService.terms.then((terms) =>
        page = TermsScreen(email: args.email, terms: terms)
        );
        break;
      default:
        page = const Center(
          child: Text('La route est inaccessible'),
        );
        break;
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page);
  }
}
```

For information, this is my `CommonService`:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class CommonService {
  final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<String> get terms async {
    String content = '';
    DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection('commons').doc('terms');
    content = (await documentReference.get()).get('content');
    return content;
  }
}
```

Define a page call my widget, so I'm blocked.

Help please. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `generate()` method is synchronous so it will execute all the way down to the `return` statement that's using the `page` local variable. Continuation functions passed to `then()` will only execute after `generate()` has completed.

In the switch statement, `page` is definitely assigned in the `default` case. But not in the other case where `page` will only be assigned a value when the function passed to `then()` executes (after the future `commonService.terms` completes -- even if the future has completed already). Since that will not happen before `return` is reached, in that case, `page` remains unassigned.

You can work around this by assigning `page` with a `FutureBuilder<T>` based on the `commonService.terms` future. When this future complete, the builder should return the expected `TermsScreen`. In the meantime, it should provide another Widget, eg a `CircularProgressIndicator`.

```dart
   case RouteConsts.termsScreen:
      ArgumentsAuth args = s.arguments as ArgumentsAuth;
      page = FutureBuilder<String>(
         future: commonService.terms,
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
               return TermsScreen(email: args.email, terms: snapshot.data!);
            } else {
               return /* some widget shown until terms completes */;
            }
         }
      );
      break;
```

Comment: Note: the builder function can also test for `snapshot.hasError` and gracefully handle situations where terms completes with an error :)

Comment: Important note: `commonService.terms` returns a new future each time the property is accessed. This could be problematic for `FutureBuilder` -- see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#managing-the-future

Comment: Nice, thanks for all, it's work fine.